# Extracting a String

Tags: java, regex

I have a string that is always built like`Mfr Part#: MBRB1045G Technologie ...` or `Mfr Part#: MBRB1545CTT4G Mounting`, so there is always `Mfr Part#:` then the `partnumber` I want to extract and then this is followed by either `Technologie` or `Mounting` entailed by other characters.

How would you extract that partnumber `MBRB1045G` from this?

Comment: I would just split on space and take the 3rd element.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc he added an ellipsis after "Technologie", he may have multiples "parts" in each line, in that case splitting is not enough.

Comment: If he needs to find a string with this pattern in order to then extract the part#, he would need a regex. If he already has the string in hand, and just wants the part#, he could just use split. It's not clear (to me) which is the case.

Comment: And finding out the additional requirements by the OP commenting on each answer is why I use a comment to answer.

Comment: excuse my English, I should have described it better than "entailed by other characters", that's what I meant. The requirement was there, just not that nicely written.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
    final Pattern pattern = Pattern
            .compile("Mfr Part#: ([^ ]+) (Technologie|Mounting).*");
    final Matcher matcher = pattern
            .matcher("Mfr Part#: MBRB1045G Mounting");
    matcher.matches();
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
```

However, if it's not important to you to check that the string has that specific pattern, you might also use the simpler expression: `Mfr Part#: ([^ ]+) .*`

Also note that you may store the pattern object and reuse it for subsequent usages. This will give you a better performance.

Comment: No match found with "Mfr Part#: MBRB1545CTG Mounting Method:..." or "Mfr Part#: MBRB1045-E3/45 Technologie:  Surface Moun..."

Comment: Oh, if you have additional trailing characters, the regex has to be slightly adjusted. Let me fix that in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably use `java.util.Scanner`. It might not be the optimal way to do so but in my oppinion the most comfortable.

It would work this way:

```
import java.util.Scaner;

String s = "Mfr Part#: MBRB1045G Technologie RZ137GA";
Scanner scn = new Scanner(s);
scn.next();
scn.next();
String partnumber = scn.next();
scn.next();
String technologie = scn.next();
scn.close();
```

The variable `partnumber` would contain `MBRB1045G` and `technologie` contains `RZ137GA`.

Answer (score 0):

Probably a regular expression with grouping would be best. (google for perlre)

```
String input = "Mfr Part#: MBRB1045G Technologie";
String regexpression = "Mfr Part#: (\\w+) (\\w+)";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regexpression);
Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
if (m.matches()) {
    String part = m.group(1);
    String desc = m.group(2);

    System.out.println(part);
    System.out.println(desc);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I see two ways to do that (and there are likely others): regexp and groups, or indexOf and substring

1) Regexp and groups

```
String input = "Mfr Part#: MBRB1045G Technologie";
Pattern p = Patter.compile("Mfr Part#: ([A-Z0-9]+) (Technologie|Mounting)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
while(m.find()) {
    System.err.println("Part number: "+m.group(1)+ "Second part is "+m.group(2);
}
```

2) indexOf and substring

```
String prefix = "Mfr Part#: ";
String input = "Mfr Part#: MBRB1045G Technologie";
for (int i=  0;i<input.length();i++) {
    int index1 = input.indexOf(prefix);
    int index2 = index1+prefix.length();
    int index3 = input.indexOf(" ", );
    int index4 = input.indexOf(" ", index3+1);
    System.err.println("Part number: "+input.substring(index2, index3)
          + "Second part is "+input.substring(index3, index4);
    index = index4;

}
```

Caveats: I have not run it so you may have to fix typos.